How does one prove that a current loop exert no net magnetic force on itself if magnetic forces do not obey Newton's third law?
For a closed current loop of arbitrary shape with current $I$ flowing, I shall focus on two infinitesimal current element $I d \mathbf{l}_1$ at $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $I d \mathbf{l}_2$ at $\mathbf{r}_2$. Using Biot-Savart law and Lorentz force law, one can calculate the force due to 1's magnetic filed on 2, $\mathbf{F}_{12}$ and the force due to 2's magnetic field on 1, $\mathbf{F}_{21}$：
$$\mathbf{F}_{12}=\frac{I^2 \mu_0}{4 \pi} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1|^3} [(d\mathbf{l}_2 \cdot (\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1))d\mathbf{l}_1 -(d\mathbf{l}_2 \cdot d\mathbf{l}_1)(\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1)]. $$
$$\mathbf{F}_{21}=\frac{I^2 \mu_0}{4 \pi} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|^3} [(d\mathbf{l}_1 \cdot (\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2))d\mathbf{l}_2 -(d\mathbf{l}_1 \cdot d\mathbf{l}_2)(\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2)]. $$
Obviously, they don’t generally cancel each other. Or in other words Newton's third law is not satisfied here.
Now I always had an expectation that one isolated object cannot exert net force on itself. Otherwise wouldn't one be able to make some perpetual motion machine out of it?
For gravitational force and electrostatic force, the force between two infinitesimal elements obey Newton's third law and can cancel each other. Following this one can easily prove there is no net force. Now that magnetic force do not obey the third law, how do one prove that a closed current loop of arbitrary shape does not exert force on itself? Or maybe for magnetic forces a closed current loop of arbitrary shape just can exert force on itself? But then wouldn't it mean that some closed loop of current cannot stay still? Or is it the magnetic field that is exerting force on it?

It's possible to show that the first term in each integral vanishes when the loops 1 & 2 are closed loops. So Newton's Third Law still holds for physical current configurations.

(And the other term is manifestly antisymmetric when you exchange the labels of the loops, so it will integrate out to zero if you're calculating a self-force on a loop)

@MichaelSeifert yeah, the second term cancel neatly. "first term in each integral vanishes ...", so do you mean if it is about two closed current loops of arbitrary shape, the first term integrates to 0? does this entail that when i calculate self-force of an arbitrary closed current loop, i can just treat it as a limiting case where two closed current loops are the same and at the same place? so does this simply proves that self-force is zero? anyway, i think the integration techniques you have in mind would be very helpful. would you please provide a source or some hints?

@MichaelSeifert and after reading your comment i realize i could be more specific that i do mean closed loops of current. i made some corresponding edits in the question.

@MichaelSeifert i guess i get what you are saying. writing dl1 as dr1, or dl2 as dr2, the first term becomes a total derivative which lead to a vanishing result when integrated over a closed loop.

I'm traveling right now so I don't have the citation in front of me;  but I believe that proving this is an exercise in Chapter 5 of Griffiths, and he gives some hints on how to do so.  IIRC the "total derivative" trick you mention is involved in the proof.
